# Global array not updating when I call a Firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a few lines of code which retrieve data from a Firebase realtime database. I want them to grab a name from objects stored there and then use this to pick a random name.  do this by first retrieving all objects and storing the name values in an array. I then retrieve the number of total objects in that database and use the random function to generate a random number, and then pick that value from the array. I am not sure why this is not behaving as it should. Here is the code I am using:

```
const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('names');


dbRefObject.on('value', gotData);
var names = [];
function gotData(data) {
    dbRefObject.once('value', function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var childData = childSnapshot.val().names;
            names.push(childData);
        })
        namesUpdated(names);
    }
    )
    return names;
}

function namesUpdated(names) {
    randomNumber = randomNumberGenerator();
    console.log(randomNumber);
    console.log(names[randomNumber]);
    return names[randomNumber];
}

function randomNumberGenerator() {
    dbRefObject.on('value', (snap) => {
        var totalRecord = snap.numChildren();
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * totalRecord);
    });
}
```

I am not sure why this is not working as when I print out the names array in gotData function it works fine. However when I try to use this in namesUpdated it says the value is undefined. Similarly, the randomNumberGenerator works fine as it returns a value in that function but does not work when I use it in namesUpdated. That function looks fine to me so I am not sure why it isnt working. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code. I'll try to identify the main ones and I would suggest you update your question with a new version.

First, IMHO, you should move the declaration of the `names` array IN the `gotData()` function:

```
  function gotData(data) {
    var names = [];
```

Secondly, in the `randomNumberGenerator()` function you should use `once()` instead of `on()`. You should also do `return dbRefObject.once('value', (snap) => {...})`.

Then, in `namesUpdated()`, you should note that the call to `randomNumberGenerator()` returns a Promise, therefore you cannot do `var randomNumber = randomNumberGenerator();`. You should either use `then()` or use `async/await`.

Finally, by separating your code in different functions, you are fetching the database several times, without any added value.